Kinematics.yaml not found for custom robot
I configured my custom robot using the moveit_setup_assistant. I have 3 planning groups, which have kinematics solver as KDL.
I have written a sample scrip to move the robot's end effector to a position in x,y,z.
The script is similar to the hello_moveit script for panda robot, just the planning group changed.
Script:
#include <memory>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Initialize ROS and create the Node
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto const node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(
      "hello_moveit", rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true));

  // Create a ROS logger
  auto const logger = rclcpp::get_logger("hello_moveit");

  // Create the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface
  using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface;
  auto move_group_interface = MoveGroupInterface(node, "m2_arm");

  // Set a target Pose
  auto const target_pose = [] {
    geometry_msgs::msg::Pose msg;
    msg.orientation.w = 1.0;
    msg.position.x = 0.28;
    msg.position.y = -0.2;
    msg.position.z = 0.5;
    return msg;
  }();
  move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(target_pose);

  // Create a plan to that target pose
  auto const [success, plan] = [&move_group_interface] {
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan msg;
    auto const ok = static_cast<bool>(move_group_interface.plan(msg));
    return std::make_pair(ok, msg);
  }();

  // Execute the plan
  if (success)
  {
    move_group_interface.execute(plan);
  }
  else
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(logger, "Planning failed!");
  }

  // Shutdown ROS
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

[13:18]
The code is being compiled, but not running. I am getting this error:
$ ros2 run move_to_point move_to_point

[INFO] [1727077580.160899404] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 2.45382 seconds
[INFO] [1727077580.161207742] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'physics'...
[WARN] [1727077584.133943068] [moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[INFO] [1727077584.161831296] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group m2_arm.
[INFO] [1727077584.162127753] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[INFO] [1727077584.165055121] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[INFO] [1727077589.368985214] [move_group_interface]: Planning request aborted
[ERROR] [1727077589.369581420] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::plan() failed or timeout reached
[ERROR] [1727077589.369792965] [hello_moveit]: Planning failed!

I tried porting the entire config folder in my custom package, but still it is unable to find the kinematics.yaml file.
How can I possibly solve this?
My system configurations are:

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
Built Moveit2 from source.

For panda and fanuc, both the hello_moveit worked, without the kinematics.yaml error.

You have identified the issue: You're missing a dedicated kinematics.yaml file.
For more information, I'd suggest that you refer to the documentation on how to describe the kinematic properties of your robot in the moveit ecosystem (in short, how to write your own kinematics.yaml file)
Another thing that you can do is to see where the kinematics file is being loaded - usually, it should be passed as a parameter somewhere in the launch file. It might so be that even though you've copied over the file, you did not point it to the right file inside the correct package.
If this indeed is the issue (setting up the robot with MoveIt setup assistant did not create the proper kinematics.yaml file), I'd also urge you to open an issue on the GitHub repo so that this can be addressed.
